# why i get the same result by jquery + ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc3 project by c#.the view is

```
     @section PageScripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlHttpRequest;

    function GetTime() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/RealTime",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    document.getElementById('lblTime').value = result;
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
    }
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Index</h2>

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="lblTime" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnGetTime" value="Get Time" onclick="GetTime();" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The Controller is

```
 [HttpGet]
    public string RealTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second;            
    }
```

when i click the button named btnGetTime several times then i got the same result.
Home can i get the different result by click the button?

Comment: one possible reason is the caching of the resource.. so try to set the option `cache: false` in the ajax call

Comment: also just as a tip: do not mix up jquery and plain js (e.g. your success handler). Also make sure your action is delivering the expected result when you call it without jquery

Answer (score 1):

I think, you must empty the "lblTime" before you parse new value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/RealTime",
        type: "get",
        // Add statement empty value
        beforeSend : function(){
            document.getElementById('lblTime').value = null;
        },
        success: function (result) {
            document.getElementById('lblTime').value = result;
        }
    });
});
```